# rails app not starting anymore: Exception NoMethodError in PhusionPassenger::Railz::ApplicationSpawner (undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

After updating gems and cleaning old versions a rails 2.3.11 app doesn't restart anymore in production.

this comes from the Apache log:

```
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /var/www/vhosts/infinitize.com/subdomains/support/rails/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
*** Exception NoMethodError in PhusionPassenger::Railz::ApplicationSpawner (undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass) (process 19800):
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:178:in `add_spec'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:89:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:89:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:89:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:960:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:960:in `_deprecated_source_index'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/deprecate.rb:39:in `skip_during'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:959:in `_deprecated_source_index'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/deprecate.rb:63:in `send'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/deprecate.rb:63:in `source_index'
    from /var/www/vhosts/infinitize.com/subdomains/support/rails/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in `add_frozen_gem_path'
    from /var/www/vhosts/infinitize.com/subdomains/support/rails/config/boot.rb:47:in `load_initializer'
    from /var/www/vhosts/infinitize.com/subdomains/support/rails/config/boot.rb:38:in `run'
    from /var/www/vhosts/infinitize.com/subdomains/support/rails/config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
    from /var/www/vhosts/infinitize.com/subdomains/support/rails/config/boot.rb:122
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/www/vhosts/infinitize.com/subdomains/support/rails/config/environment.rb:11
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:299:in `preload_application'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:248:in `initialize_server'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:255:in `report_app_init_status'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:233:in `initialize_server'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:194:in `start_synchronously'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:163:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:209:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:262:in `spawn_rails_application'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:126:in `lookup_or_add'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:256:in `spawn_rails_application'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:80:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:255:in `spawn_rails_application'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:154:in `spawn_application'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:287:in `handle_spawn_application'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/bin/passenger-spawn-server:61
```

Anybody any clue?
I have been upgrading/downgrading rubygems-update, but I keep getting this error:

```
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
```

Answer (score 0):

A long shot but you might have something like this in your gemfile...

gem 'mysql'

change to...

gem 'ruby-mysql'